# Why is Minecraft Magic Launcher playing 1.5.2 instead of 1.7.3/1.7.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

Whenever I open Magic Launcher and hit login, the title screen says Minecraft 1.5.2. And, when I play there aren't any horses or anything from the new update.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: Why use Magic Launcher when you can just use the default Minecraft launcher? They both do the same thing now.

Comment: Voting to leave this question open. As per community consensus at the meta posts: [Minecraft crash questions should be made off-topic: yes/no?](//meta.arqade.com/q/10390), [Why just ban Minecraft modding tech support?](//meta.arqade.com/q/10568), [What exactly is technical support?](//meta.arqade.com/q/11015) and [Update the off-topic reason for "Technical support for non-vanilla Minecraft"…](https://meta.arqade.com/q/13542), only *crash* issues and other technical issues related to *running* modded Minecraft are off-topic. It's not off-topic if the game runs fine without crashing.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Magic Launcher](http://www.6minecraft.net/magic-launcher/) you go to Setup -> Environment and select 1.7.4. If it's not there, you have to download it with the vanilla launcher first.